# verifying Ramanujan constant

Tags: computational-mathematics, machine-precision

The famous Ramanujan constant $ e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} $ is a near-integer.

see the link [here.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanConstant.html)

I tried to calculate this number with matlab and failed. Matlab cannot even deliver the first 9 apparently because of the double float precision.

```
     2.625374126407683e+17
```

It seems that we need a customized algorithm. Could anyone give a hint?

Comment: Even using an [arbitrary precision calculator](https://github.com/lcn2/calc) you will never get close to $\displaystyle e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$, no chance ;) -- maybe _close enough_ according your flavour.

Comment: In Matlab via the Symbolic Math toolbox: `R=exp(sym(pi)*sqrt(sym(163))), vpa(R)`, which returns `262537412640768743.99999999999925`.

Comment: In IEEE double precision math, the largest consecutive integer is `2^53` (roughly `9.0072e+15`), as provided by `flintmax` in Matlab. The Ramanujan constant is larger than this so the nearest representable double integer is `262537412640768736.0` (i.e., `double(R)`).

Answer (score 2):

Throwing this into
Wolfram Alpha,
my goto for stuff like this,
I get

2.62537412640768743999999999999250072597198185688879353856337... × 10^17

with a continued fraction of

[262537412640768743; 1, 1333462407511, 1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, ...].